# Cassandra 4.1.4 Planned Release

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-4.0

We need this release done in order to migrate to version 4.1.4 and have the fix for Security Vulnerability (Upgrade snappy java library) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18878

We cannot move to version 5 of Cassandra as is still a Beta and is not allowed by our management to use Beta Versions while 4.1.3 still have this Vulnerability Issue inside it. So we are stuck => either we have a new Cassandra 4.1.4 released or you Release Cassandra 5.0 but make it official.

We created a build based on this cassandra 4.1.4 branch for testing on linux GitHub - apache/cassandra at cassandra-4.1 and the vulnerability was not there. We expect the official release so we can reference

Comment: Voting to close as A) this isn't about programming and B) I can't really tell what the actual question is.

Comment: Does anyone know when Cassandra 4.1.4 release will be made? The developers of Cassandra suggested to add the question over here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-19258

Comment: The Cassandra user mailing list (user@cassandra.apache.org) is probably the best place to ask that question. Most folks on Stack Overflow are not going to have a window into that.

Comment: They did not tell you to ask on Stack Overflow, they said _"by reaching out to the community on slack or the ML"_ (where ML presumably stands for mailing list). This type of question is considered unsuitable for Stack Overflow, and off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Circling back to this; in case you're not checking the mailing list, a release of Apache Cassandra® 4.1.4 is currently up for a vote. If it passes, 4.1.4 should be released next week sometime.

Here's a list of what is included in that build, which includes CASSANDRA-18878:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/4.1.4-tentative/CHANGES.txt

Comment: I am not aware of the voting system for certain release you are using but we are desperately looking forward having this release done so we can move forward with fixed securities vulnerabilities that it contains. If there is a way for external guys to vote I would gladly give 100 votes to get this release done now and do not wait any further as I can see all the issues raised on this particular version ar fixed.

Comment: @NicolaeOprean Cassandra 4.1.4 was just released! Check the downloads page. https://cassandra.apache.org/_/download.html